# How to add JLabel to every first row, first col in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel

I am trying to add the label "Day/Time" to each first row/col for each grid. It seems that it is adding only to the last grid. Please see attached image. Highlighted in yellow are the grids where I want to add my Label "Day/Time"

Attached is the code:

```
    private void buildGridPanel() {
    for (int countRoom=0; countRoom < roomPanels.length; countRoom++) {
        roomPanels[countRoom] = new JPanel();
        roomPanels[countRoom].setLayout(new GridLayout(ROW, COL));
        roomPanels[countRoom].setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));

        if (countRoom == 0) {
            roomPanels[countRoom].setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(roomList[countRoom]));
        } else if (countRoom == 1) {
            roomPanels[countRoom].setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(roomList[countRoom]));
        } else {
            roomPanels[countRoom].setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(roomList[countRoom]));
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
                //create new panel for every grid
                JPanel pan = new JPanel();

                pan.setEnabled(true);
                pan.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                pan.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(3, 3));
                pan.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
                // an exception to not click the top row and most left column
                // headers
                if (i != 0 && j != 0) {
                    pan.addMouseListener(new BoxListener()); // add a mouselistener to make the grid panel clickable
                }
                // set names for each panel for later use
                if (countRoom == 0) {
                    pan.setName(roomList[countRoom] + "_" + i + "_" + j);
                    if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
                        pan.add(labelDayTime);
                    }
                } else if (countRoom == 1) {
                    pan.setName(roomList[countRoom] + "_" + i + "_" + j);
                    if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
                        pan.add(labelDayTime);
                    }
                } else {
                    pan.setName(roomList[countRoom] + "_" + i + "_" + j);
                    if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
                        pan.add(labelDayTime);
                    }
                }

                // add the panel to the room panels
                roomPanels[countRoom].add(pan);


            } // end  for loop COL
        } // end for loop ROW

        // add each room panels to the center panel
        centerPanel.add(roomPanels[countRoom]);
    } // end for loop


}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A component can only have a single parent and can only exist on one part of a panel at any given time.

You need to create multiple JLabels and add each JLabel separately to the panel.

Comment: That helps me a lot! Appreciate your help!

Comment: @tdel, glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.